# Problems configuring rvm and `bundler not installed`

Tags: rvm, bundler

I am a novice having major problems with rvm. `bundle install` gives me the error

```
`ERROR: Gem bundler is not installed, run `gem install bundler` first.
```

even though I know it *is* installed, as it shows up if I run `gem list -l`. I suspect that's returning a list of system gems, which would suggest that rvm is definitely the problem. Trying `gem install bundler` again doesn't help. I've looked around at other people who have had similar problems and can't find an answer that helps whatever situation I'm in. `rvm info` gives me this output:

```
# rvm info

system:

  system:
    uname:       "Linux box576.bluehost.com 2.6.32-20130101.60.1.bh6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jan 1 22:59:09 EST 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"
    system:      "unknown/libc-2.12/x86_64"
    bash:        "/ramdisk/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)"
    zsh:         "/usr/bin/zsh => zsh 4.3.10 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.18.8 (master) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
    updated:      "22 hours 59 minutes ago"

  homes:
    gem:          "/home7/contenw6/ruby/gems"
    ruby:         "/home7/contenw6/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/home7/contenw6/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/home7/contenw6/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/home7/contenw6/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/home7/contenw6/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/usr/local/jdk/bin:/home7/contenw6/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@projecta/bin:/home7/contenw6/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/home7/contenw6/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/home7/contenw6/.rvm/bin:/home7/contenw6/perl5/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/ramdisk/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/home7/contenw6/ruby/gems/bin:/home7/contenw6/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     "/home7/contenw6/ruby/gems"
    GEM_PATH:     "/home7/contenw6/ruby/gems:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/home7/contenw6/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194"
    IRBRC:        "/home7/contenw6/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

If I do `rvm use 1.9.3-p194@projecta --default` the environment section now looks like this:

```
  environment:
    PATH:         "/home7/contenw6/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@projecta/bin:/home7/contenw6/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/home7/contenw6/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/home7/contenw6/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/jdk/bin:/home7/contenw6/perl5/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/ramdisk/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/home7/contenw6/ruby/gems/bin:/home7/contenw6/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     "/home7/contenw6/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@projecta"
    GEM_PATH:     "/home7/contenw6/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@projecta:/home7/contenw6/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/home7/contenw6/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194"
    IRBRC:        "/home7/contenw6/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       "projecta"
```

but when I log in and try again it reverts back to the first output above. I've clearly screwed something up somewhere, and I have no idea how to fix my installation or where the problem is coming from. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this looks like your previous ruby settings, check your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshenv` for any variables set that might contain the mentioned paths

if you do not find anything try checking in `/etc`:

```
grep -rn "/home7/contenw6/ruby/gems" /etc
```

update from comments:

```
sed -i'' '/GEM_HOME=/ d;' ~/.bashrc
rm ~/.gemrc
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to use this information. I am a complete newbie who has very little idea what I'm talking about. I included the readouts above just because I thought it would help. I don't really know how `PATH` works or what it should look like. I just want bundler and the rest of my gems to work.

Comment: `~/.bashrc` contains the line `export GEM_HOME=$HOME/ruby/gems`. What should I change this to? Or should I remove it?

Comment: After commenting out that line, my environment looks okay on login. But I still can't use `bundle install`. It returns `ERROR: Gem bundler is not installed`.

Comment: what do you see from: `which -a bundle`

Comment: `/home7/contenw6/.rvm/bin/bundle`
`/home7/contenw6/ruby/gems/bin/bundle`

Comment: looks like your PATH is broken: echo $PATH

Comment: `/usr/local/jdk/bin:/home7/contenw6/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@projecta/bin:/home7/contenw6/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/home7/contenw6/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/home7/contenw6/.rvm/bin:/home7/contenw6/perl5/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/ramdisk/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/home7/contenw6/ruby/gems/bin:/home7/contenw6/bin`

Comment: the `gem` wrapper was supposed run for you `hash -r` but it appears no accessible, try after running `hash -r`, also if it does not help what is your `gem env` again

Comment: - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.24
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2012-04-20 patchlevel 194) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home7/contenw6/ruby/gems
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home7/contenw6/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home7/contenw6/ruby/gems/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home7/contenw6/ruby/gems
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
[...]
     - "gemhome" => "/home7/contenw6/ruby/gems"
     - "gempath" => []
     - "rdoc" => "--inline-source --line-numbers"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/

Comment: you can see INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home7/contenw6/ruby/gems is still wrong, check your ~/.gemrc ... actually just delete it

Comment: THANK YOU! That solved it. Thanks for being so patient with me. I'm still learning, and am doing my best to figure out this stuff as I go along. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This one was helped me

```
cd ~/.rvm/bin
rm bundle
```

Then return to you project folder install a bundler gem and run bundle w/o problems